# Scanf giving "expected parameter declarator" error despite having parameter declarator

Tags: c, compiler-errors, scanf

I am trying to create global variables from an input using scanf. I have this code to do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* innitialize our default global variables */
int height[2] = {0, 0}; /*verticle height will be the first number when splitting, aka the number of rows*/
int barrier = 0;
int fill = 0;
int point[2] = {0, 0}; /*verticle height, aka row number, will be the first number*/

/*set the variables*/
scanf("%d %d", &height[0], &height[1]);
int array[height[0]][height[1]]; /*create array with designated size*/
scanf("%d", &barrier); /*set the barrier*/
scanf("%d", &fill); /*set the fill*/
scanf("%d %d", &point[0], &point[1]); /*set the point*/
```

But I generate these errors when making:

```
prog0.c:11:7: error: expected parameter declarator
scanf("%d %d", &height[0], &height[1]);
      ^
prog0.c:11:7: error: expected ')'
prog0.c:11:6: note: to match this '('
scanf("%d %d", &height[0], &height[1]);
     ^
prog0.c:11:1: error: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-int]
scanf("%d %d", &height[0], &height[1]);
^
prog0.c:11:1: error: conflicting types for 'scanf'
/usr/include/stdio.h:446:24: note: previous declaration is here
extern int __REDIRECT (scanf, (const char *__restrict __format, ...),
                       ^
prog0.c:12:5: error: variable length array declaration not allowed at file scope
int array[height[0]][height[1]]; /*create array with designated size*/
    ^     ~~~~~~~~~
prog0.c:13:7: error: expected parameter declarator
scanf("%d", &barrier); /*set the barrier*/
      ^
prog0.c:13:7: error: expected ')'
prog0.c:13:6: note: to match this '('
scanf("%d", &barrier); /*set the barrier*/
     ^
prog0.c:13:1: error: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-int]
scanf("%d", &barrier); /*set the barrier*/
^
prog0.c:13:1: error: conflicting types for 'scanf'
/usr/include/stdio.h:446:24: note: previous declaration is here
extern int __REDIRECT (scanf, (const char *__restrict __format, ...),
                       ^
prog0.c:14:7: error: expected parameter declarator
scanf("%d", &fill); /*set the fill*/
      ^
prog0.c:14:7: error: expected ')'
prog0.c:14:6: note: to match this '('
scanf("%d", &fill); /*set the fill*/
     ^
prog0.c:14:1: error: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-int]
scanf("%d", &fill); /*set the fill*/
^
prog0.c:14:1: error: conflicting types for 'scanf'
/usr/include/stdio.h:446:24: note: previous declaration is here
extern int __REDIRECT (scanf, (const char *__restrict __format, ...),
```

and it continues to repeat these errors for each scanf before timing out from too many errors. Researching scanf and formatting, as far as I can tell I'm doing it correctly. My best guess is that scanf does not work on a global scope. Is this the issue?

Comment: You need a main function.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'm pretty sure this *is* the MCVE, hence the compiler errors.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `main` function. This is in chapter one of your beginner's C text book. Without a `main` function no program code can run.

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* innitialize our default global variables */
int height[2] = { 0, 0 }; /*verticle height will be the first number when splitting, aka the number of rows*/
int barrier = 0;
int fill = 0;
int point[2] = { 0, 0 }; /*verticle height, aka row number, will be the first number*/


int main()
{
  /*set the variables*/
  scanf("%d %d", &height[0], &height[1]);
  int array[height[0]][height[1]]; /*create array with designated size*/
  scanf("%d", &barrier); /*set the barrier*/
  scanf("%d", &fill); /*set the fill*/
  scanf("%d %d", &point[0], &point[1]); /*set the point*/
}
```

Comment: I did not forget it. It is later and does a lot of other things. I was trying to set all of these as global variables, including the array, since I would be editing the array in multiple functions and wanted to do it without having to pass pointers. I take it though that that means; yes, scanf does not work on a global scope?

Comment: @JosephSquires Statements in general cannot be outside of a function.

Comment: @you need have all your initialisation code in `main` or in some initialisation function of yours you call at the beginning of `main`.